# Nothing Known About ... when using ri Array -- Ruby

Tags: ruby, rvm, rdoc, ri

I have Ubuntu 11.10 and am using rvm with ruby 1.9.2. I followed this exactly to install Ruby: http://blog.sudobits.com/2011/10/27/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-in-ubuntu-11-10/

I generate the docs with

```
rvm docs generate
```

This seems to work for a one time terminal session, but as soon as I exit out and start again, I have to generate the docs again, otherwise i get the Nothing is Known error This takes a long time, so I rather not have to generate the docs every time I start a terminal session.

Is there anything I can do to permanently have the docs available?

There are definitely similar questions to this -- but I don't have a problem with generating the docs, or using them, just keeping them installed.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is what I did to install ri docs on my Ubuntu box (I'm not using RVM):

```
gem install rdoc rdoc-data
rdoc-data --install
```

Comment: I get the error
ERROR: While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems

Comment: try to run it with sudo. It should work with RVM without problem

Comment: ok, that worked to install it. but still when i try something like ri Array -- i get Nothing known about Array.

Comment: It may be a problem with rdoc version. Look at these links: [1](https://github.com/rdoc/rdoc-data), [2](http://blog.segment7.net/2010/03/31/rdoc-2-5), [3](http://buzzcodington.wordpress.com/2011/04/), and [4](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.ruby.general/347732)

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install ri1.9.1`